Android device opens Play Store instead of calendar app on intent url
I'm dispatching an intent url for android devices using python.
This is the relevant code:
description = (
        u"Nom de l'établissement: {}\n"
        u"Identifiant Etablissement: {}\n"
        u"Fin des ventes: {}\n\n"
        u"Classe: {}\n"
        u"Carte d'accès: \n"
        u"        • Identifiant: {}\n"
        u"        • Mot de passe: {}\n"
        u"Accès au site: {}\n"
    ).format(org.name, org.id, org.sales_close_date, event.title,
             access_card.access_id, access_card.access_code,
             access_card.link)
encoded_description_google = description.replace(u'\n', u'%0A')
        if request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', '').lower().find('android') > -1:
            google_url = (
                u"intent://view?id=com.google.android.calendar&package=com.google.android.calendar&" 
                u"startDate={}&endDate={}&title={}&description={}"
                u"#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.google.android.calendar;end"
            ).format(
                start_date_str, end_date_str, cal_event_title, encoded_description_google
            )

I tried to open this url on my pixel using chrome, kiwi, brave and firefox but always play store opens instead of the calendar app. I tried the same with outlook and the result was the same, play store opened with the google calendar and outlook apps page.
I have tried adding explicit #Intent and package. I also used view but it didn't help. I have also checked app settings, for calendar 'Open by default' is on. and for play store under open by default, in verified links I didn't see any calendar links so I don't know what am I doing wrong here.
Thankyou in advance.
